# Moving container contents and remounting volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

On an old server running docker I have a two containers running ipam and mysql. The mysql has mounted a volume and after stopping the containers, I copied the contents of the volume to a new server, into the directory:
`/mnt/dockerdata/vols/ipam/phpipam-mysql`

Next I create a volume on that new server: `docker volume create --driver local --opt device=/mnt/dockerdata/vols/ipam/phpipam-mysql phpipam-mysql --opt type=volume`

Next I created a docker-compose.yml file to try and make this repeatable. Not really needed here, but I want to learn for other projects. So I created this file: (I'm aware of the password, but it is just my lab)

```
services:
  ipam-mysql:
    container_name: ipamdb
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=P@55F0rIP@M
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - phpipam-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  ipam:
    container_name: ipambase
    depends_on:
      - ipam-mysql
    image: pierrecdn/phpipam
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=P@55F0rIP@M
      - MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_HOST=mysql
    ports:
      - "192.168.0.10:80:80"
volumes:
  phpipam-mysql:
    external: true
    name: phpipam-mysql
```

But this returns the following errors:

```
Building with native build. Learn about native build in Compose here: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-native-build/
Creating ipamdb ... error

ERROR: for ipamdb  Cannot create container for service ipam-mysql: failed to mount local volume: mount /mnt/dockerdata/vols/ipam/phpipam-mysql:/var/lib/docker/volumes/phpipam-mysql/_data: no such device

ERROR: for ipam-mysql  Cannot create container for service ipam-mysql: failed to mount local volume: mount /mnt/dockerdata/vols/ipam/phpipam-mysql:/var/lib/docker/volumes/phpipam-mysql/_data: no such device
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

When I don't use the `external:true` option, a new empty volume is created which I don't want. I tried creating the volume with the type ext4 but that doesn't change the error.

Any tips?

Comment: Can you directly put the host directory name in the `ipam-mysql` container `volumes:` block, instead of trying to indirectly use a Docker named volume?

Comment: I could do that, that actually is the example given with this docker file. But I read in the docker documentation that it is better to use volumes. Plus I want to have all volumes used by docker on a different disk for easier transfer to a new system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume you create is set to mount a device, not a folder, therefore the `no such device` error.

To create a volume binded to a folder:

```sh
volume create --driver local --opt device=/mnt/dockerdata/vols/ipam/phpipam-mysql phpipam-mysql --opt type=none --opt o=bind
```